# textview background color is lost during screen rotation

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm trying to fix a bug in this app called mizuu, there is a Horizontal Card Layout for movies and tv shows of a select actor, there a button to show more on the upper right hand side corner of the layout which has a grey background color but when rotating orientation to landscape mode and vice versa the background color of "see more" text is lost , is there a way to solve this issue?

files

> actor_details.xml
>
> horizontal_grid_items.xml
>
> HorizontalCardLayout.java
> https://pastebin.com/s6uPkBht

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_dark"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/content_details_baseline_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/content_details_baseline_margin"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/content_details_baseline_margin">

            <com.miz.views.HorizontalCardLayout
                android:id="@+id/actor_movie_cards"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/details_medium_padding" />

            <com.miz.views.HorizontalCardLayout
                android:id="@+id/actor_tv_cards"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/details_medium_padding" />

            <com.miz.views.HorizontalCardLayout
                android:id="@+id/actor_photo_cards"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/details_medium_padding" />

            <com.miz.views.HorizontalCardLayout
                android:id="@+id/actor_tagged_photo_cards"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/details_medium_padding" />

        </LinearLayout>
 

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/see_more"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:background="@color/card_background_dark"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:text="@string/see_more"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@color/card_title_color"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/horizontal_card_layout_title_padding"
        android:visibility="gone" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this issue occurred because of code in your activity somehow make this view gone, i suggestion set configChanges orientation in AndroidManifest.

```
 <activity
           ...
           android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout"
```

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes

Comment: Thank you that didn't work unfortunately , I added the code to my question can you please check it